# Safari not able to reproduce 8k video from youtube

Tags: safari, video, youtube

I'm trying to see the new 8k videos on Youtube with Safari but when I choose the 8k quality I get an error: **an error occured, please try again later.**

An example of video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChOhcHD8fBA&t

When I choose 4k works fine.

I'm using a Macbook Pro 15" with touchbar with Radeon Pro 460.

Any idea why this is happening? someone is able to see the video?

Comment: I can select 8k video in Chrome, and it appears to play OK (but I don't have an 8k screen). The highest resolution Youtube shows me in Safari (`settings` -> `Quality`) is 1440p. For reference, my largest screen is 2880x1800.

Answer (score -1):

With Chrome you can play it. It looks like Safari is not compatible with 8k.